# Error when building Eclipse workspace OLD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I had a issue which is a commonly raised question regarding Android Eclipse in stackoverflow.

Eclipse is taking too much time to build the workspace. This started after I tried to update both ADT bundle and SDK. I followed many steps to solve this, which I've gone through the stackoverflow

i.e:

1.Uncheck the Build Automatically from Project Tab
2.Window - > Preferences - > Android -> Build -> Skip packaging and dexing export or launch.(Speeds up automatic builds on file save) etc etc....

But the issue is still there.

System Config:
RAM - 4GB &
Win 7(OS)

Comment: After doing the above have you restarted eclipse?

Comment: @Zedaiq .. I restarted eclipse after the steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try all of the following to speed up your current IDE (apart from buying a SSD):

- Increase Eclipse memory availability editing eclipse.ini (XXMaxPermSize and such)
- Remove/uninstall non-Android related and unused plugins
- deactivate validators and spell checkers
- start Eclipse using `--clean` option

I noticed a notable performance degradation using Eclipse to develop Android apps since when I started, at SDK 7. I warmly suggest you to switch to Android studio, as it is now [The official Android IDE](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). [Migration](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) is almost straightforward and you'll get many advantages, native Android wear support and a much more effective and integrated dev environment.

Gradle, the new build tool used by default, builds the workspace incrementally, only re-compiling units and modules as needed. I guess it's up to 30% faster than Eclipse in building it up.

This answer is counter-biased since I'm a fan of Eclipse